# php strip_tags not outputting whole string

Tags: php, strip-tags

i have this table as a variable i want to use strip_tags function on:

```
<?php $tbl='
<table id="patients">
    <tr>
        <th>Pt. username</th>
        <th>Pt. number</th>
        <th>Full Name</th>
        <th>Added on</th>
    </tr> <tr><td><a href="profile.php?username=fringo123"</a>fringo123</td>
                   <td>3</td>
                   <td>fringo123 shreiwekh</td>
                   <td>2014-02-12 22:16:53</td>
                   </tr> <tr class="alt"><td><a href="profile.php?username=kamal"</a>kamal</td>
                   <td>24</td>
                   <td>kamal kab</td>
                   <td>2014-03-06 03:01:24</td>
                   </tr> <tr><td><a href="profile.php?username=kissaye"</a>kissaye</td>
                   <td>20</td>
                   <td>shreiwekh</td>
                   <td>2014-03-03 14:34:59</td>
                   </tr> <tr class="alt"><td><a href="profile.php?username=maas12345"</a>maas12345</td>
                   <td>7</td>
                   <td>maas12345</td>
                   <td>2014-02-13 20:23:56</td>
                   </tr> <tr><td><a href="profile.php?username=maas123456"</a>maas123456</td>
                   <td>8</td>
                   <td>maas123456</td>
                   <td>2014-02-13 20:25:51</td>
                   </tr> <tr class="alt"><td><a href="profile.php?username=marly"</a>marly</td>
                   <td>9</td>
                   <td>Marly Mario</td>
                   <td>2014-02-19 22:02:50</td>
                   </tr> <tr><td><a href="profile.php?username=mohamad"</a>mohamad</td>
                   <td>10</td>
                   <td>mohamad salem</td>
                   <td>2014-02-19 22:27:48</td>
                   </tr> <tr class="alt"><td><a href="profile.php?username=rami1234"</a>rami1234</td>
                   <td>6</td>
                   <td>rami1234</td>
                   <td>2014-02-13 20:21:48</td>
                   </tr> <tr><td><a href="profile.php?username=ramizmo"</a>ramizmo</td>
                   <td>25</td>
                   <td>ramy om</td>
                   <td>2014-03-06 03:26:52</td>
                   </tr> <tr class="alt"><td><a href="profile.php?username=saeed"</a>saeed</td>
                   <td>16</td>
                   <td>Saeed Shaweesh</td>
                   <td>2014-02-28 21:59:37</td>
                   </tr> <tr><td><a href="profile.php?username=sheeerokh"</a>sheeerokh</td>
                   <td>21</td>
                   <td>sheeerokh mo7sen</td>
                   <td>2014-03-03 14:43:45</td>
                   </tr> <tr class="alt"><td><a href="profile.php?username=sheeerokh22"</a>sheeerokh22</td>
                   <td>22</td>
                   <td>sheeerokh mo7sen22</td>
                   <td>2014-03-03 14:45:50</td>
                   </tr> <tr><td><a href="profile.php?username=shinyor"</a>shinyor</td>
                   <td>23</td>
                   <td>shinyor kalb</td>
                   <td>2014-03-03 14:47:40</td>
                   </tr></table>';
```

when i run strip_tags i only get the four table head parts but not the rest of the table. what am i doing wrong please? this is what i get:

Pt. usernamePt. numberFull NameAdded on

Comment: Your HTML is malformed in many places `?username=fringo123"</a>`

Comment: the link refers to the user's profile page. whats wrong with using an argument in url to be retrieved with $_GET ?

Comment: the link(s) are missing closing `>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just to close the  bracket for example.

```
<a href="profile.php?username=fringo123"</a>fringo123
```

to

```
<a href="profile.php?username=fringo123">fringo123</a>
```

etc.